# VS 2015 Release Management Tokenize XPath/Regular expressions not working

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I'm trying to set up a token replacement for my config files. I have the source filename set to:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TFS Web Build 1.0/Corporate Art\app.RM.config
```

(Here, the RM file is the tokenized config file using token)

The destination filename is set to the true name of the config file:

```
Company.Client.Corporate.exe.config
```

I have the json file on the build server at:

```
\0111-03-0555-01\c$\BuildFiles\Transforms.json
```

The transforms.json file has the following data in it:

```
[
{
"CompanyTestDomain": {"QA4"},
"Environment": {"QA4.com"},
"CheckForContext": {"true"},
"ServiceTierAppHost": {"0111-06-0555-00-01.Company.com"},
"ServiceTierCsHost": {"0111-03-0444-00.Company.com"},
"ReportServer": {"0777-02-0111-00-01.Company.com"},
"ReportID": {"systemID"},
"ReportDomain": {"Corp"},
"ReportPWord": {"Password"}
}
]
```

The powershell is executed `C:\Users\Public\Downloads\agent\tasks\Tokenizer\2.0.2\tokenize.ps1`

The next line is grey as opposed to black which all the other information is:

```
##[debug]Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item:
C:\Agent_work\85c7a0d97\TFS Web Build 1.0\CorporateArt\app.RM.config
Destination: C:\Users\Public\Downloads\agent\tasks\Tokenizer\2.0.2\Isagenix.Clients.CorporateBackOffice.exe.config.tmp".
```

after which, I start getting messages that it's Updating token 'CompanyTestDomain'
No value found for token 'CompanyTestDomain'

So, can someone help me figure out what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use web-based release management or server-based release management? Which task you used? Provide the details of your release management definition. How about this task: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks

Comment: I am using the web-based release management. The task is noted in the title of the post: "VS 2015 Release Management Tokenize XPath/Regular expressions" At least that's the name that comes up.  I think that is the one you reference.   I have a build that is linked to a release.  The only task I have at the moment, is this one task.  What else are you looking for in terms of definition information?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Answer (score 0):

The content of configuration file should be like this (Contains a section ConfigChanges)

For example:

Sources file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="TestKey1" value="__Token1__" />
      <add key="TestKey2" value="__Token2__" />
      <add key="TestKey3" value="__Token3__" />
      <add key="TestKey4" value="__Token4__" />
    </appSettings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Configuration file content:

```
    {
  "Default Environment": {
    "CustomVariables": {
      "Token2": "value_from_custom2",
      "Token3": "value_from_custom3"
    },
    "ConfigChanges": [
      {
        "KeyName": "/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='TestKey1']",
        "Attribute": "value",
        "Value": "value_from_xpath"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Variable in release definition: **Token4 t4**

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TestKey1" value="value_from_xpath" />
    <add key="TestKey2" value="value_from_custom2" />
    <add key="TestKey3" value="value_from_custom3" />
    <add key="TestKey4" value="t4" />
  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

More information, you can check these articles ([1](https://github.com/openalm/Extension-UtilitiesPack/blob/master/Utilites/overview.md), [2](https://the.randomengineer.com/2016/05/06/using-tokenization-token-replacement-for-buildsreleases-in-tfs-2015/)).

Comment: Is there an idiots guide to this?  Is the first one the tokenized config file?    Is the second one the json file?  
I have a line in a web.config that is as follows:
<add key="GoogleAnalytics" value="__GoogleCode__" />

I want to replace the __GoogleCode__ with  the following:
US-12349809-5

What should the json file look like?  
{
"Default Environment": {
     "CustomVariables": {
         "GoogleCode": "US-12349809-5"
}

Comment: @JCollier The first one is your source file (web.config), the second one is the configuration file (json file). The json file should look like { "Default Environment": { "CustomVariables": { "GoogleCode": "US-12349809-5" } and web.config file likes <add key="GoogleAnalytics" value=" __GoogleCode__ " />. (This task finds the pattern  __<pattern>__) . Articles: https://github.com/openalm/Extension-UtilitiesPack/blob/master/Utilites/overview.md and https://the.randomengineer.com/2016/05/06/using-tokenization-token-replacement-for-buildsreleases-in-tfs-2015/